# IntelliJ deploys a web application with Tomcat. What controls where the log files go?

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

When I deploy my web application under tomcat/catalina from the command line, my logs go in /logs

Not so when IntelliJ launches it.  Where are the logs and what setting decides where the logs go?

This is a project I inherited so the default settings may have been messed with.  Telling me where the setting is entered would add additional value over just telling me the default.

I have investigated the 'logs' tab of the tomcat launch configuration and this appears not to determine where the logs go but rather to read logs that are already in a known location.

Can't find those logs.

**update** the logging framework appears to be log4j

Comment: I've normally seen my Tomcat logs make their way to the Console tab, but not the Tomcat Console tab (unless Tomcat itself blew up).  Further to that, which logging framework are you using?

Comment: The classes doing the logging in the code are all org.apache.log4j.Logger

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found is to print that logs in your standard tomcat output logs in intelli. I try it in intellij-idea 14.

You have to change your log4j.xml like this :

add in your xml this part

```
 <appender name="default.console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
   <param name="target" value="System.out" />
   <param name="threshold" value="debug" />
   <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%c{1}] - %m%n" />
   </layout>
 </appender>
```

and this

```
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="default.console" />
 </root>
```

Comment your other logger

```
<!--<logger name="LOGGER_NAME">
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="DEFAULT_LOGGER" />
 </logger>-->
```

Now you can read your logs on your default tomcat output.

**EDIT**

Another way to see directly the out put log is look at this path :

*C:\Users\your_user_name.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\your_project_name\logs*

inside this folder you can find your logs files and you can clean them up.

Answer (score 0):

you can find your tomcat logs in directory

*C:\Users\user\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\webapp*

Goodbye